# EC2で運営しているサイトのメールフォームからsendmailを利用したメール送信ができない

Tags: aws, sendmail, amazon-ec2

AWSのEC2を用いてホームページを作成しているのですが、そのホームページにお問い合わせ(メールフォーム)のページを作成しようと考えています。
そこで、こちらのフリーのメールフォームを用いようと頑張っているのですが、どうもうまくいきません。
http://www.synck.com/contents/download/cgi-perl/mailform_jcode.html

EC2のほうでSMTPのポートを解放し、CGIの動作環境を整え、メールフォームを使用するためのJcodeを導入し、
フォームから送信ボタンを押して、「送信できました」という画面までは表示されるようになったのですが、メールが届きませんでした。

sendmail がうまく動いていないのかな？と考え、EC2にsshでログインし

```
$ sudo sendmail <送信先のメールアドレス>
```

と、メールを送信したところ、メールが届きませんでした。

```
$ sudo service sendmail status
```

で、sendmailが動作していることは確認しました。

ですので、まずはsendmailがEC2で正しく動かせるように、いろいろ行っているのですが、
メールを送信できませんでした。
どうすれば、正しくsendmailを動作させることができるでしょうか。

また、メールフォームからメールを送信できない他の理由は考えられるでしょうか。

追記(2016/05/19 18:38)=============================================
「サブミッションポートを使う」ということでセキュリティグループに
EC2サーバのほうで インバウンド カスタムTCP(587) を設定し、
sendmail.mc内の

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=submission, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl
```

のコメントアウトを解除してサブミッションポートを使用するようにしました。

しかし、seamailの動作テストを以下のようにして

```
$ sudo sendmail ***@softbank.ne.jp
$ From:support@<ドメイン>
$ To:***@softbank.ne.jp
$ Subject:テスト送信
$
$ テスト送信です
$ .
```

/var/spool/mail/ec2-user を確認したところ送信失敗していました。

```
...(略)
Arrival-Date: Mon, 16 May 2016 09:25:09 GMT

Final-Recipient: RFC822; \*\*\*@softbank.ne.jp
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; [127.0.0.1]
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550 5.1.1 <\*\*\*@softbank.ne.jp>... User unknown
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 16 May 2016 09:25:45 GMT

--u4G9P9UN003320.\*/ip-\*-\*-\*-\*.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
...(略)
```

さらに、User unknown とあったので
local-host-names のファイルに ドメインを追加したのですが、うまく動作しませんでした。

Comment: `550 5.1.1 <\*\*\*@softbank.ne.jp>... User unknown` 宛先間違いか、迷惑メール扱いでフィルタされてるかもしれませんね。迷惑メールにならないための対策をしてみると良いかもしれません。私の回答に追記しておきます。

Answer (score 2):

TCP/25はブロックされてるのでサブミッションポート(TCP/587)を使ってください。

Amazon SES を使う方法もあります。アマゾンのスライドショーが参考になると思いますのでご紹介しておきます→[AWSからのメール送信](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServicesJapan/aws-30934799)

**迷惑メールにならない為の対策**

1. サーバーによっては 接続元が実在するか DNS でチェックする場合があります。

   - DNS ドメインの MX レコードが有るかどうか
   - ehlo (helo) で名乗ったホスト名を DNS クエリで正引きできるか
   - IP を逆引きして ehlo (helo) で名乗ったホストと一致するかどうか
   - MX と A レコード は Route53 を使うか、既にお使いの DNS で設定してください。
   - 逆引きは AWS に申請が必用です [申請フォーム](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request)
2. 加えて AWS では次の対応を推奨しています。SES と Rotue53 を使うと 設定は自動化できるので面倒であればSESとRoute53を使ってください。

   - SPF(Sender Policy Framework)/Sender ID を設定する
   - DKIM(DomainKeys Identified Mail) を設定する
3. RBL に 現在使用中のEIPが登録されてないかチェックする

   - EIP は使い回しなので 過去の使用者が スパマーで IP がブラックリストに乗っている可能性があります。RBL に登録されていないか検索して 載っていれば EIP を再度取得すると良いでしょう。
   - [Request to Remove Email Sending Limitations](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) で RBL からの登録解除の申請もできるようです。
4. 携帯キャリアによっては メール本文をチェックしています。本文が1行だけのメールは ブロックされることもあります。

SMTP サーバーを立てるのは色々と面倒ですので、送信専用であれば SES と Route53 を使って EC2 の sendmail は SES にリレーするのがオススメです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。SESの使用も考えたのですが、使用する前にsendmailが正しく動くことを確認してくださいとあったので、sendmailが動くようになったら、SESを検討しようと思っています。
「サブミッションポート(TCP/587)を使う」にはセキュリティグループでTCP/587を解放するだけでよいですか？

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます、これをもとにまた設定してみます。一つお伺いしたいのですが、ドメインはお名前ドットコムで取得し、そのドメインをGMOの共有サーバSDのメールサーバで使用しています。DNSは共有サーバSDに登録してあり、AレコードをAWSのEC2のIPに登録しています。つまり、メールサーバとサイトのサーバが別の状態です。MXレコードは共有サーバSDで登録してあります。この環境でも行うことは同じでしょうか？

Comment: 大変申しわけありません。とても初歩的な質問なのですが、検索してもでてこなかったので聞かせてください。ehloコマンドが見つからず、実行できませんでした、ehlo‌​はどのように導入するのでしょうか。

Comment: ①ehloはSMTPプロトコルのメッセージです。導入する必用はなく、sendmailが送信先に接続した際に送信するコマンドです。sendmailに設定した自分自身のホスト名がDNS解決出来ればよいです。②MXレコードの件ですが、MXが既に有るなら、一旦MXのことは忘れてもらっていいと思います。ドメインからMXが引けて、MXのホストのAレコードが存在する、及び、EC2サイトのホスト名を正引き、逆引きできる状態であれば良いと思います。一通り設定するのは中々大変ですので、2. で書いた内容は後回しでも良いかも知れません。

Comment: アドバイスに従いAWSの逆引きを申請しました、反映までしばらくかかりそうです。SPFについてですが、共有サーバSDのほうで[v=spf1 ip4:<EC2のEIP> -all]と設定しました、正しいでしょうか。
DKIMについては知識がありませんので、現在勉強中です。RBLも確認したところ、ブラックリストには載っていませんでした。

Comment: SPFには「GMOの共有サーバSDのメ‌​ールサーバ」についても書く必要があります。メールサーバのIPはわかりますか？わかるなら ①GMOのメールサーバのIP、②EC2のEIPを書く必要が有ると思います。`v=spf1 ip4:<GMOのIP> ip4:<EC2のEIP> -all` でしょうか。「-all」は SPF レコードに書かれていないサーバーからのメールは「FAIL」であり偽装メールとして拒否されますので 貴方のドメインから送信する可能性のあるIPは 全て書くと良いと思います。IPが分からない場合は `include` で GMOのSPFレコードを含めると良いと思います `v=spf1 ip4:<EC2のEIP> include:gmo.jp -all` でしょうか。`gmo.jp`の部分は私が想像で適当に書いてますので 間違ってるかもしれません。何をインクルードするべきか 可能でしたら GMOに問合せて見てください。

Answer (score 1):

「送信できました」という画面が表示されるということは、おそらく、メールフォームと同じホストで稼働する sendmail を使ってメールを送ろうとして、メールキュー (/var/spool/clientmqueue/, /var/spool/mqueue/) には入るけれど、そこから外部に送信できない状況ではないかと思います。

以下を確認ください。

- sendmail サービスは起動していますか？
- メールキュー (/var/spool/clientmqueue/, /var/spool/mqueue/) にファイルはありませんか？
- メールログ (/var/log/mailog, /var/log/mail.log など)には何かエラーは出ていませんか？

OS、sendmail のバージョンと sendmail の設定、ログがあると、何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: sendmail はstatusを確認したところ、runningとなっており稼働していると思います。/var/spool/mqueueにファイルはありましたが、コマンドラインでsendmailした場合は /var/spool/mail/ec2-user にログが残っておりました。エラーについては、追記の通りです。OSはAmazonLinux(Linuxのパッケージ)です。sendmailのバージョンはVersion 8.14.4です。

Comment: 補足「/var/spool/mqueueにファイルはありましたが、」と書きましたが、当初ファイルがあったのですが、いろいろ設定をして動作テストなどを行っているうちに、ここのファイルがなくなっていました。現在もsendmailやフォームからメールを送信しても、そのディレクトリにファイルがたまることはありません。

Comment: /var/spool/mqueu/ のキューが再送され、そのエラーメールが /var/spool/mail/ec2-user です。
メールログは別途確認した方がいいと思います。
エラーメールによると、応答コード 550、メッセージが「User unknown」です。
宛先メールアドレスが正しいのであれば、「User unknown」はダミーで SPAM 扱いされているのかもしれません。
対応は take88 さんの回答のとおりです。